# Split me in half

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion, binary

You will be given a  number `x`, where `0 <= x <= 2^32 - 1`.

You should output a list of numbers in decimal, after recursive splitting in binary format.

#### Examples:

**Example 1:**

```
255 -> 255 15 15 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The current list is just `255`.

The binary representation of `255` is `1111 1111`. Splitting it, we get `1111` and `1111`, which in decimal are `15` and `15`.

We add those to the list, so we will have `255 15 15`.

Now the numbers `15` and `15` will serve as inputs and these numbers are to be split.

Doing it again, we get (`3 3` from both `15`s): `255 15 15 3 3 3 3`.

Continuing the logic, final list will be `255 15 15 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` . And since `1` can no longer be split, the output stops.

**Example 2:**

```
225 -> 225 14 1 3 2 1 1 1 0
```

The starting list is `225`.

The binary representation of `225` is `1110 0001`. Splitting it, we get `1110` and `0001`, which in decimal are `14` and `1`.

Adding those to the list, we get `225 14 1`.

Now the numbers `14` and `1` will serve as inputs and these numbers are to be split.

Since `1` is no splittable,  the output will be `225 14 1 3 2`.

**Example 3:**

```
32 -> 32 4 0 1 0
```

**Conditions**:

1. If the number of binary digits are odd, the first number will have one fewer binary digit than the next one. Example, `20 (10100)` will be split as `10` and `100`, with decimal output being `2` and `4`.
2. Standard loophole rules apply.
3. `0`s and `1`s do not propagate further.
4. Program crashing for trying to display too many numbers is a valid exit condition.

Comment: @Satan'sSon If you pad in front, that's equivalent to the description.

Comment: Is the specified output order required or just the values?

Comment: @Satan'sSon No padding with `0`s.

Comment: @JonathanAllan The specified output order is required.

Comment: Suggesting different title of "Split **this** in Half".

Answer (score 14):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
u+QiR2smc2+0dt#.BM
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BQiR2smc2%2B0dt%23.BM&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=255%0A225%0A32&debug=0)

This code does something very tricky and clever with `u`, Pyth's fixed point operator.

The body of the function, which is everything other than the `u`, is fairly straightforward:

```
+QiR2smc2+0dt#.BM
+QiR2smc2+0dt#.BMG    Implicit variable
                      G will store the list of numbers from the previous iteration.
              .BMG    Map each number to its binary representation
            t#        Filter out the ones of length 1 (0 and 1)
      m               Map the remaining binary
         +0d          Prefix with a 0
       c2             Chop in half.
                      Since c puts the larger half first, prefixing with a 0
                      makes the chop work out right, and doesn't change the value.
     s                Concatenate
  iR2                 Map back to binary
+Q                    Add the input to the front of the list
```

This code removes 0s and 1s, splits every number, and adds the input in front.

`u` will run this function on the prior result of the function until the result stops changing.

What initial value does `u` use? That's the clever part: the code doesn't specify what value to use, so it defaults to the input. But the input isn't a list of numbers - it's a number. Pyth implicitly coerces the number on the fist time through the loop to the range of the number - `[0, 1, ..., Q-1]`. That doesn't look anything like the output we want to get. Fortunately, `u` will find the correct result regardless of what the initial input is - the desired output is the only fixed point of the function, and repeated application will always reach it.

Let's look at the intermediate values of the program with the input `7`. I've highlighted the prefix of the result which is guaranteed to be correct, regardless of initial input:

1. `7` (Implicitly `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`)
2. **`[7,`**`1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]`
3. **`[7, 1, 3,`**`1, 0]`
4. **`[7, 1, 3, 1, 1]`**

Which is the output.

---

## Packed Pyth, 16 bytes

Note that since Pyth uses only the 0-127 range of ASCII, it can be compressed by using a 7-bit encoding rather than an 8 bit encoding. Thus, the above program can be packed into 16 bytes. The resulting program is:

```
ꮎ�L����[
    ���4
```

hexdump:

```
0000000: eaae 8e9a 4cb9 edc6 c95b 0c9d 11ae 8534  ....L....[.....4
```

The interpreter is found [here](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/master/packed-pyth.py). Provide the input as a command line argument.

The code page of this language (Packed Pyth) is the 0-127 range of ASCII, and every character is represented with 7 bits, padded at the end. Thus, the above unreadable hexdump represents:

```
u+QiR2smc2+0dt#.BM
```

But in 16 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
,¸[Žrbvy0ì2äCʒ=1›
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AR4A4f//LMK4W8W9cmJ2eTDDrDLDpEPKkj0x4oC6//8xNjc)

### Explanation

```
,¸[Žrbvy0ì2äCʒ=1›   Argument n
,¸                  Print n and push n as array
  [Ž                Loop until stack is empty
    r               Reverse stack
     b              Convert elements in array to binary
      v             For each y in array
       y0ì2ä        Prepend '0' to y and split it into 2 elements
                    (the first element will take the additional character)
            C       Convert elements to decimal
             ʒ=1›   Keep only elements greater than 1, while printing each element
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yep fixed it now. Seems to be a problem the examples do not cover, thanks :)

Comment: `ʒ` - This new codepage... Since when is 05AB1E Jelly? Me likey.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte by removing a monadic chain and then dealing with the consequence of an empty list being converted from binary yielding 0 later.

```
ỊÐḟBUœs€2UḄF
WÇÐĿṖUF
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning the list specified.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASsA1P//4buKw5DhuJ/CtUJVxZNzMlXhuITCteKCrEYKV8OHw5DEv1VG////MjI1)**

#### How?

```
ỊÐḟBUœs€2UḄF - Link 1, perform an iteration: list of numbers
 Ðḟ          - filter out if:
Ị            -   insignificant (absolute value <= 1 - hence any 0s or 1s)
   B         - convert to a binary list (vectorises)
    U        - upend (reverse each)
     œs€2    - split €ach into 2 equal chunks (the first half is longer if odd ...hence
         U   - upend (reverse each)         ...this upend and the previous one)
          Ḅ  - convert from binary list to number (vectorises, although when the filter
             -                                     removes everything a zero is yielded)
           F - flatten the resulting list of lists to a single list

WÇÐĿṖUF - Main link: number
W       - wrap in a list
  ÐĿ    - loop and collect results until no change occurs:
 Ç      -   call last link (1) as a monad
    Ṗ   - pop (remove the last element - a list containing a single zero which results
        -     from the effect of Ḅ when link 1's input only contained ones and zeros)
     U  - upend (put the iterations into the required order)
      F - flatten to yield a single list
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @Satan'sSon I added an explanation just now

Comment: You added it at the same time I commented :D

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen both ways have the same byte cost

Comment: Oh, didn't see the Pyth answer first, which already used that trick.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes

This looks a bit too long. There might be a better way to get the correct order.

```js
f=(n,p=(a=[],1),i=33-Math.clz32(n)>>1)=>(a[p]=n)>1?f(n>>i,p*=2)&&f(n&(1<<i)-1,p+1):a.filter(n=>1/n)
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,p=(a=[],1),i=33-Math.clz32(n)>>1)=>(a[p]=n)>1?f(n>>i,p*=2)&&f(n&(1<<i)-1,p+1):a.filter(n=>1/n)

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(255)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(225)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(32)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>541</s> <s>521</s> <s>245</s> 243 bytes

```java
n->{var L=new java.util.Stack<Integer>();L.add(n);for(int i=9,o=0,t;o<i;)for(i=o;i<L.size();o++)if((t=L.get(i++))>1){var b=n.toString(t,2);L.add(n.parseInt(0+b.substring(0,t=b.length()/2),2));L.add(n.parseInt(b.substring(t),2));o++;}return L;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVE9b8IwEN35FTfaAlyaiqEyZq@UsjBWHZzEpAfBRvaFqkX57elBEGJo1cXy@d6Xnrf2aKfbateXjU0JXi360wgAPbm4saWD1XkE2DJOtYSNyjHR4oX3tYtLKMX1Cl5qRnYjPhJZwhJW4MFA76fL09FGyI13n3dCa7Ll7qYkpM6VrSrBOpsQBScANM@TYGYT0mGBWl6eTdC4yFXCb8eUMB5L3AhBJle1I4E8y@WjvBgWxisKa4roa0GT7OagDjYmx85iNi5Uaos0YNjJFKpxvqYPIR8yyZxfSPcUGjCcQ3fRURs95Lrr9bmGQ1s0XMO1jWPACvbcrxgSvb2DlUO5669Ebq9CS@rAK2o825Uim8/lpdS/Edl/iKdMXv@l638A)

-22 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                      // Method with Integer parameter & Integer-List return-type
  var L=new java.util.Stack<Integer>();
                          //  Create the result-List
  L.add(n);               //  Add the input-Integer to it
  for(int i=9,            //  Index integer `i`, set to a non-0 digit
      o=0,                //  Off-set integer `o`, starting at 0
      t;                  //  Temp integer `t`, uninitialized
      o<i;)               //  Loop as long as `o` isn't `i` yet:
    for(i=o;i<L.size()    //   Inner loop `i` in the range [`o`,list-size):
        ;o++)             //     After every iteration: Increase `o` by 1
      if((t=L.get(i++))   //    Set `t` to the `i`'th item
                          //    (and increase `i` by 1 afterwards with `i++`)
         >1){             //    If `t` is larger than 1 (thus can be further split):
        var b=n.toString(t,2);
                          //     Convert `t` to a binary-String
        L.add(            //     Add to the List:
          n.parseInt(     //      A String converted to Integer:
            0             //       A "0",
            +b.substring( //       Appended with a substring of `b`
               0,t=b.length()/2)
                          //       in the char-range [0,length/2)
          ,2));           //      Converted as a base-2 String to base-10 Integer
        L.add(            //     Also add to the List:
          n.parseInt(     //      A String converted to Integer:
            b.substring(  //       A substring of `b`
              t)          //       in the char-range [length/2,length)
          ,2));           //      Also converted from a base-2 String to base-10 Integer
        o++;}             //     And increase `o` by 1
  return L;}              //  Return the result-List
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 110 bytes

```python
l=[input()];i=1
while i:
 z=0
 for k in l[-i:]:
	if k>1:b=~-len(bin(k))/2;l+=[k>>b,k&2**b-1];z+=2
 i=z
print l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#BcFBCsMgEADAc/cVeyqaVFqFXpT1I@JFSOjiYkNIKXjI183MEErctt@hdA5MFv4flgXZA3Z6Aa7fHStyQ0mGffZw4xVrtL7QaWRpqnBTVeunCzJTqjGWR727aSrG5tBncoBMHbad24EyhnPvCw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 142 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
{`.+$
$&¶<$&>
+`;(\d*)>
>;<$1>
<.>

{`(\d)>
>$1
}`<(\d)
$1<
<>
;
\b0+\B

}`^;|;\B

¶
;
;;

1
01
+`10
011
0\B

1+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#FY7RCcMwDET/bw5hkgiMFeiXhD4yhymmdIs0a2WALOZKf6d3h@5mZdAGHovw2gV0ytXQBIJzVCZQeW6j4hHRpX@31eFqJA6rjggFTEaCa1geIDGYQ9E/jfuBMN7601TPHVgV8T46eEh2hU5PYkktc@776w8)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 132 Bytes

```php
for($r=[$argn];""<$n=$r[+$i++];)$n<2?:[$r[]=bindec(substr($d=decbin($n),0,$p=strlen($d)/2)),$r[]=bindec(substr($d,$p))];print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#bY1BCsIwEEX3HqPMIkMCSsCNk6EHCaFYUzUgY0jr@dPRtcv3@I8fxvqsB7i2h7D3Z@r3dzPQOP5UomEIIAwtWijWJkKQ4MdLVJN4LpKXm1k/87pplVlJnQFBd3JQWfVrUc549Ijub6Q7xES1Fdmm7zdS7zs)

Comment: This does not work, according to the Try it online system in this page,

Comment: @MartinBarker what do you mean?

Comment: https://tio.run/nexus/php#bY1BCsIwEEX3HqPMIkMCSsCNk6EHCaFYUzUgY0jr@dPRtcv3@I8fxvqsB7i2h7D3Z@r3dzPQOP5UomEIIAwtWijWJkKQ4MdLVJN4LpKXm1k/87pplVlJnQFBd3JQWfVrUc549Ijub6Q7xES1Fdmm7zdS7zs => `Array(    [0] => 225    [1] => 14    [2] => 1    [3] => 3    [4] => 2    [5] => 1    [6] => 1    [7] => 1    [8] => 0 )` when it does not = 255 15 15 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: @MartinBarker You must change the input in the header Version. Change the variable `$argn` This variable is available if you running PHP from the command line with the `-R` option. Here is an example for input 255 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#bY1BCsIwEEX3HqPMIkMClUA3ToYeJASxpmpAxpDW88fRtcv3@I8f5vqoB7i0u7CfJuq3VzPQOP5UomEIIAwtWijWJkKQ4OdTVJN4KZLXq9ney7ZrlVlJnQFBd3RQWfVzVc44ekT3N9IdYqLaiuzn7zdS7x8 "PHP – TIO Nexus")

Comment: That's what i was trying to say it did not work according to the try it online system. (linked in the post)

Comment: @MartinBarker understand I am you right you want a output like this? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#bYtBCsMgEADvfUWQPbgotAi9VJc8RDwk0TYpRcWk77dLzznOMOPGutYLTO2VyZi77c/SJDTyfxWsEA4yQfMKNqWCRcjOjA/PJtC85ZgWuX/n/eArEhM7CRn1TUMl1p/EHPFqEPXpxB1isGlZy/AufItBcIm29x8 "PHP – TIO Nexus") instead of printing the array directly join it first to a space separeted string? Other answers do the same that they modify the output to save some bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 102 bytes

```ruby
f=->*a{a==[]?[]:a+=f[*a.map{|i|s='%b'%i;i>1?[s[0...h=s.size/2].to_i(2),s[h..-1].to_i(2)]:[]}.flatten]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#PcnBCoJAEADQu1/hIbEsJ12QBWP0Q4ZBNthtB7SEXQhSv92gQ9f3dodlV5jFIBL3xK05o6PCwGTmZZU1YJ7d80xu0tU9BaoAwGOAIB97VQzxNchRnS6BPEBZ/4Fb4g3caGK0T972OXV0GH7Lby@jTR82hl01TaKqRGv9BQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 98 bytes

```ruby
f=->*a{a==[]?a:a+=f[*a.flat_map{|i|s='%b'%i;i>1?[s[0...h=s.size/2].to_i(2),s[h..-1].to_i(2)]:[]}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#PcjBCoJAEADQu1/hIbEsJ12QBWP0Q4ZhmcBtF4yEXQhSv32DDr3jSxbroZJVEIlH6eWMlioBO0s0T1nWzW8By@JeFv7mh3akQA0AOAwQ/Ge6Kob4Mv6oTpdADqBu/8E98c57WnJLB/Nbfjs/T/ljiiGprstUk2mtvw)

Simply a basic optimization of [Value Ink's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121504/split-me-in-half/121691#121691) : use flat_map instead of map...flatten, and use

`a==[]?a` instead of `a==[]?[]`

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
{gÉo1>môàh½‼<≥å}∟;
```

Takes the input wrapped inside a list. If this is not allowed, a leading `a` can be added.
Print each of the resulting items on a separated line to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/786/XBnvqFd7uEthxdkHNr7qGGPzaPOpYeX1j7qmG/9/3@0kalpLFe0kRGINDYCEgZAbAgSAtEGsQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
{              }∟  # Do-while true without popping:
 g                 #  Filter the current list of integers by
                   #  (or the implicit input-list in the first iteration),
  É                #  using the following 3 characters as inner code-block:
   o               #   Print the integer with trailing newline (without popping)
    1>             #   Check that it's larger than 1 (thus can be further split)
      m            #  Map over the remaining integers,
       ô           #  using the following 6 characters as inner code-block:
        à          #   Convert the integer to a binary-string
                   #   Split it into the correct halves by:
         h         #    Pushing its length (without popping)
          ½        #    Integer-dividing this length by 2
           ‼       #    And apply the following commands separated on the stack:
            <      #     Slice to get the first length//2 bits
             ≥     #     Slice to get the remaining bits
              å    #  After the map: convert all binary-parts back to integers
                 ; # After the do-while: remove the empty list from the stack
                   # (the empty stack is then output implicitly with newline)
```